# emacs - add decimal value to column of numbers

Tags: emacs, macros

I'm working with some nastran input files that have the following structure:

```
GRID,1,,0.000,0.000,0.000,0
GRID,2,,0,000,1.653,0.000,0
```

What I would like to do is add a specific value to a single column, for example, add 1.653 to the 4th column and get:

```
GRID,1,,0.000,1.653,0.000,0
GRID,2,,0,000,3.306,0.000,0
```

I've found a few example that show how to do this for [integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686593/emacs-adding-1-to-every-number-made-of-2-digits-inside-a-marked-region) but can't seem to get this to work for the example I've outlined above.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the answer in the linked question it can be done with replace like this, for example:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

`^\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)`

<kbd>return</kbd>

`\,(concat \1 (number-to-string (+ 1.653 (string-to-number \2))) \3)`

Note that in your example the second line has more columns (commas) than the first. Probably a typo.

Comment: yes, extra comment should be a period.  Thanks for the response.  Is there a good resource for how to construct those expressions?  I think this is my main problem...

Comment: Probably there are such resources, but I can't tell you one right now. You may want to ask the guys on the emacs help list about that: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help

Answer (score 0):

Respective as command

```
(defun raise-column ()
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\\)\\([^,]*\\)\\(.*\\)" nil t 1)
        (replace-match (concat (match-string-no-properties 1) (number-to-string (+ 1.653 (string-to-number (match-string-no-properties 2)))) (match-string-no-properties 3)))))))
```